# PHP delete cookie that starts with wp_postpass_

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I need to write some custom code for a Wordpress function, and I need to be able to delete any cookies that start with `wp-postpass_`. I know this can be done with jQuery but I'm unsure of how to approach it in PHP.

I have tried Googling and searching on here but I haven't been able to find anything that matches what I'm trying to do.

Thank you in advance,
Andy

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I should have mentioned that Wordpress appends a random string onto the end of `wp-postpass_` hence why I need to find any cookies that *start* with `wp-postpass_`. Apologies, early morning.

Comment: What did you tried yet, show us some code.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, because I don't know the best approach. I've said that in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So iterate through all cookies and check if there contain `wp_postpass_` and then remove the cookie.

```
foreach($_COOKIE as $cookieKey => $cookieValue) {
    if(strpos($cookieKey,'wp-postpass_') === 0) {
        // remove the cookie
        setcookie($cookieKey, null, -1);
        unset($_COOKIE[$cookieKey]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, would this also remove the cookie `test_wp_postpass_something`?

Comment: Yes it will because he check if "wp_postpass_" is in the string, not if it's at the beginning of the string. === 0 instead of !== false

Comment: Okay I've tried this too and it appears the cookie is still valid in the page resources

Comment: @AndyHolmes i edited it, now it unset the cookie in the current page too

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the $_COOKIE superglobal just do

```
$past = time() - 86400;
foreach($_COOKIE as $name => $value) {
    if(strpos($name, 'wp-postpass_') === 0) {
        setcookie($name, '', $past);
        unset($_COOKIE[$name]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The setcookie function just say "delete them from the browser when sending the answer". If you want to also delete them from the current script call, you need to add a little code line.

I have added a line to delete from the current context too.

Comment: Tried that too and it's still there? haha

Comment: Maybe it's WP that recreate them just behind. Either you want to clear the current context, or remove them from further request.

Comment: They are the same except for the cookie value and expire date. I would be curious, if yours solve this case while mine don't, why it happens.